# How do I make this random image generator function the background image of a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am hoping to make this random generating array of images a 'background-image' as I want those properties for the images (most importantly I want the height of the image to always be the size of the browser.)
I can't figure out how I would make that happen using css/html and I am not sure how to call on this function to be a background image in my script - any ideas or advice on how to do that?

script/html as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>

<link href="css/uikit.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript">

var random_images_array = ['light.jpg', 'dark.jpg', 'photo.jpg'];
    
function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
    path = path || 'images/'; // default path here
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var img = imgAr[ num ];
    var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
    document.write(imgStr); document.close();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

  
 <div id="welcomeImage" class="fadeout">
    <!-- This script segment displays an image from the array -->
    <script type="text/javascript">getRandomImage(random_images_array, 'images/')</script>
</div>

<!-- or to have image linked: -->
<!--<a href="."><script type="text/javascript">getRandomImage(random_images_array)</script></a>-->


<div id="introText" class="animated fadeIn">
    <p>div text</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('welcomeImage').style.display='none';", 4000); </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showIt() {document.getElementById("introText").style.display = "block";}
setTimeout("showIt()", 5000); </script>

</div> <!-- end of #wrapper -->


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*global stylesheet*/

@charset "UTF-8";

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* so linked image won't have border */
a img { border:none; }

.fadeout {
    animation: fadeOut 1s forwards; 
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}

/*my most current attempt at fadein through CSS */
.animated { 
    animation-duration: 3s; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
} 

@keyframes fadeIn { 
    0% {opacity: 0;} 
    100% {opacity: 1;} 
} 
.fadeIn { 
    animation-name: fadeIn; 
}

#welcomeImage img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;    
}

#introText {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 100px;
    padding-left: 300px;
    padding-right:300px;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    color: purple;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 900;   
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show your CSS too. But the problem is about updating the background image and setting it to the viewport size.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Oops, I will post my CSS. I found an answer using jquery but I'm curious to know if you would have been able to think of anything with out having to link to the jquery library ... For some reason I feel like it is messy or heavy to use both jquery and javascript ? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer - achieved setting the background image with jquery, then was able to use the background-size property in CSS. Not sure what it would have looked like in javascript, but if anyone is able to translate it for me or let me know it is even possible, I would love to see how to do it in javascript to compare it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>

<link href="css/uikit.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var random_images_array = ['light.jpg', 'dark.jpg', 'photo.jpg'];

$(document).ready(function() {
    
$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + random_images_array[Math.floor(Math.random() *      random_images_array.length)] + ')'});

})

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="introText" class="animated fadeIn">
    <p>div text</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showIt() {document.getElementById("introText").style.display = "block";}
setTimeout("showIt()", 5000); </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  background-size: cover;
}
```